# How to click menu item of menu of menu bar item of menu bar in Apple Script?

Tags: macos, applescript

[The menu bar:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vojF.png)

[The UI Brower:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHcWb.png)

Apple Script:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "MacID"
        click menu item 9 of menu 1 of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: change it to "get properties of of menu bar 2", then if that checks out, try "get properties of menu bar item 1 of menu bar 2", to test that part of the path, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to do it with MacID and menu items without Command Shortkeys but here is how to do it with keystroke:

```
tell application "System Events" keystroke "(key)" using command down
```